# MIME type ('text/css') is not executable and strict MINE type checking is enabled

Tags: html, css

Refused to execute script from ......custom.css' because its MIME type ('text/css') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I have gotten answers for ('text/html') but there are no answers for /css. I do not know what this means or how to fix it. When I go to link my css file to my HTML file it wont link.... HELP

Comment: How are you trying to "link your CSS file to your HTML file"? This error message suggests you may not be using an appropriate method -- but you need to show us your code.

Comment: Please post this in an edit to your question, not in comments. Click the "edit" link under your question to edit it.

Comment: In the meantime, I do see problems in your HTML - <header> should be <head>. This causes the <link>s to end up inside the body. But I'm not sure that would cause the error message.

Comment: because i am new at using stackoverflow, i dont full understand how to put my code in when i edit my post. that being said Mr. Lister, that is what was wrong with my code. thank you for you help.